# Why does FreeQ seem not to work with complex numbers?

Tags: evaluation, complex

I guess I do not understand how *Mathematica* evaluates this simple expression inside `FreeQ`

```
a = 2 I
FreeQ[a, I]
FreeQ[2 I, I]
FreeQ[I, I]

(* 2 I *)
(* True *)
(* True *)
(* False *)
```

Comment: Check  `FullForm[a]` or `FullForm[ I ]`, etc. There are a lot of questions in the site about complex numbers an some ideas about how to cope with the difficulties that arise when trying to match them

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `FreeQ[...,Complex]`...

Comment: You are right, FullForm shows it is Complex[0, 2], and formally it does not have "I" in it. Disappointing that FreeQ works so "technically", and checks on an internal form instead of dealing with the explicit symbolic form visible to users.

Comment: Thank you, FreeQ[..., Complex] works just fine.

Comment: If you want to check the form of the expression as you entered it, you can do `FreeQ[HoldForm[2 I], HoldPattern[I]]`.

Comment: `Complex` numbers are considered atomic and containing no subexpressions in WL, e.g. `AtomQ[1 + 2 I]` gives `True`. This is mentioned in the help page for `Complex`.